# What is the difference between using virsh and qemu to create virtual machines?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, virtual-machine, qemu, kvm

I think there are two ways of creating a virtual machine.

1.Use virsh command(or GUI,virt-manager) to create a virtual machine.

2.Use qemu command (like qemu-system-x86_64)to create a virtual machine.

What is the difference between the two ways?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 2):

Virsh is the command that interact with the libvirtd in order to manage "any" hypervisor.
qemu is a Quick Emulator. This is actually the application that will provide the hardware abstraction layer for the guest VMs